# WordPress remove legacy CSS and include new CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, deque, enqueue

Trying to remove old CSS and include new CSS, however when I inspect my code I still get the old CSS and not the new, have I written the code correctly?

**My code**

```
function se_remove_styles() {
    if ( is_page_template( 'template/page-main.php' ) ) {
        wp_dequeue_style( 'styles', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/vendor.min.css',array(),'1.0.0');
        wp_enqueue_style('styles',get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/vendornew.min.css',array(),'1.0.0');
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'se_remove_styles', 99 );
```

Comment: Based on the language from the codex, `wp_print_styles` should no longer be used to `enqueue` the styles. You might need to break up the function into two separate ones. First, dequeue then enqueue. Also, you may want to give your new style a different handle. It also could be a simple caching issue. https://make.wordpress.org/core/2011/12/12/use-wp_enqueue_scripts-not-wp_print_styles-to-enqueue-scripts-and-styles-for-the-frontend/

Comment: Thanks man @disinfor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably something related to cache.

One way to update `CSS` in `Wordpress` without having to refresh the cache through the browser is to update its version.
As you see, the versions are `1.0.0` in both `CSS` you are calling. Change them to `1.0.1` and test it again. Like this:

```
function se_remove_styles() {
    if ( is_page_template( 'template/page-main.php' ) ) {
        wp_dequeue_style( 'styles', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/vendor.min.css',array(),'1.0.1');
        wp_enqueue_style('styles',get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/vendornew.min.css',array(),'1.0.1');
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm and the add action would be the same ?

Comment: Yes. Also, this was the way you were adding CSS before, right?

Comment: yes, the legacy code is wrapped in case statement but im braking free at the bottom removing some and adding new scripts

Comment: Hmm not working unfortunately old css still there and new not

Comment: Perfect juest also took into account disinfor comment and changed 'wp_print_styles'

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful!